# arrays and date in php

Tags: php, date, foreach

My var_dump looks like this, I know that I'm getting the error because I'm passing an array instead of a string. But how can I solve it?

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'date_submitted' => string '2012-03-22 19:28:22' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'date_submitted' => string '2012-03-28 21:31:28' (length=19)
```

My function

```
function getArticle() {

    $article = new Article('x');
    $arr = $article->getArticles();

    $date= null;
    foreach($arr as $record){
        $currentDate = date('l, F j', strtotime($record['date_submitted']));

        if ($currentDate != $date) {
            echo set_format_date($record['date_submitted'],'l, F j');
        }
        $date = $currentDate;
    }
}
```

Tried using `$x=0;` then `$x++;` but that returns `Undefined offset: 0`
like this `$record[$x]['date_submitted'];` , it didnt work.

Comment: "the error" - what is this "the error"? You're not passing an array to strtotime, you're passing a string member of an array, so it can't be that.

Comment: What variable are you `var_dump`ing??

Comment: @PenguinCoder I created an array called $arr, and using while looping thouch each database record and using $result->fetch_assoc(), I pushed an array to another array, $arr

Comment: Poster is probably `var_dump` `$arr` which contains all the `Article`s

Comment: You should `var_dump($record);` within the loop to see why it's telling you that.

Comment: I don't think the error lies at the `strtotime` call. Please show us the code for `set_format_date` as well - since this function isn't bundled with vanilla php.

Comment: I dont know what I did but it fixed the error. Strange. Code is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to manipulate the array itself inside a foreach loop, you have to reference the value.

```
foreach($arr as &$record){
  // ...
}
```

if you manipulate $record now inside the loop, $arr will actually contain the values you manipulated. otherwise $record is just in scope of the loop.